# Format a Stuck External Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, disk-format

I have an external drive that is basically unusable. It’s just for backups, and I have redundant backups, so I don’t care about losing the data, I just want to completely format it and get it working again. (I highly doubt it is a physical issue with the drive)

This is basically the state the drive is in now:

- The drive has two partitions
- One partition will mount, but cannot be unmounted, even forcing through Terminal
- The other partition will never mount
- Whenever the drive is connected, Disk Utility will stop working

Comment: What OS? I had a drive that would kill Disk Utility on Yosemite unless I connected it at or just after boot. El Capitan never exhibited the same issue. Maybe have a look at this http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205866/85275 [from para 7, bear in mind that user wanted to hide 2 boot drives from each other, so modify the method for a single drive] to persuade Finder not to auto-mount it

Comment: @Tetsujin El Capitan

Comment: This would help other people. Mind if I undelete it and +1 the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the drive to respond and unmount by killing the process fsck_hfs