# Remove access/ permissions to internal HDD

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, ssd, permission, spotlight

Is there any way to remove my permissions to the internal HDD of an iMac? I'm booted from an external SSD and spotlight shows default apps twice and sometimes some apps start from the internal HDD.

To stop confusion and any problems I would like to disable all my permissions to the internal drive. I found some terminal commands for that in the past but can find them anymore...

The standard way without terminal to set permissions doesn't work because I can't remove all my permissions. It has to be either read, write or both.

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Do you need the HDD at all or could you just unmount it?

Comment: @nohillside I don't need it at all. I could unmount it, but every time I reboot it will be back. And I thought it would be faster/ easier to just remove all permissions.

Comment: It would be faster/easier to add it to fstab to prevent it mounting - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414678/limit-application-launching-to-boot-disk-only

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, you are awesome as always! Only thing: `diskutil info` looks like it changed. I found it in multiple answers and it always throws an error for me on how to use it correctly. Doesn't matter if I just write the name of the volume or add `/Volumes/My-Volume/`

Comment: `diskutil info` doesn't need a path, just a drive name - `diskutil info Macintosh\ HD` though I never have any drives called "Macintosh HD" mine all have space-free actual names, so there's never any confusion. [BTW, even on Monterey, I'm still using bash, every time I launch terminal it tells me I should change something… I never have]

Comment: @Tetsujin Alright, I have to escape the space didn't know that, thanks! It's the default drive, so I didn't rename it. Thanks for your fast help!

Answer (score 1):

- Open System Preferences
- Enter "Spotlight" in the search box on top and pick the first hit
- Switch to the Privacy tab
- Add the HDD mountpoint (`/Volumes/...`)

Comment: Well yes, thanks. That would solve the Spotlight problem. But not that some old apps for some reason start from the HDD, because the user somehow managed to put the wrong app in the autostart.

Comment: @jona It might be easier to prevent mounting the drive then, see the comment beneath the question.