# How to disable "Eject device before disconnecting or turning it off." finder notification

Tags: macos

I have an external mic with storage built-in, and every time I unplug it (or turn the monitor off, which cuts power to the mic) I get an **notification** shown in the screenshot: `Disk not ejected properly`. It is an 'Alert' style notification because it persists until I clear it. I don't want to eject the device every time I turn off the monitor or unplug it. I don't even use the storage on it. I don't care about corruption like this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/368404/335980).

Can I disable this alert some how, or make it less obtrusive? I used to okay with it in the previous macOS, but in Big Sur this notification is more annoying to clear away.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can eliminate this warning.
Normally you shouldn't even think of eliminating it, but I can see your use-case for not needing it for this specific device.

I would be more inclined to prevent the volume from mounting in the first place, then it will never 'not be properly ejected'.

You can prevent it from mounting using `fstab`.
I wrote an earlier answer on using this, so I'll link to that rather than covering the same ground again. The question itself is entirely unrelated, but the answer contains step by step for `fstab`
I do not know, however, if this still works as advertised in Big Sur, with the protected OS partition. Someone else would have to help you through that, if it's not mutable any more.
[Time Machine restore to new partition, different computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205814/time-machine-restore-to-new-partition-different-computer)

Comment: Thanks, this is great advice and instruction.